# Delete a custom row from table by clicking button

Tags: php, database, delete-row

This code is working for me but by clicking the button, nothing changes. The delete results are seen only after I refresh again my page manually. 
Is there anything to add to fix this issue?

```
<?php
 foreach($results as $value){
     echo "<tr>";
     echo "<td class='posts column-posts'>".$value->id."</td>";
     echo "<td class='email column-email'>".$value->email."</td>";
     echo "<td class='description column-description'><div id='col-container'>".$value->details."</div></td>";
    $delRow = "delete_registration_{$value->id}";
     echo "<td class='posts column-posts'><input type='submit' name= $delRow value='delete'/></td>";
     echo "</tr>";
     if(isset($_POST[$delRow])){
         $wpdb->delete( 'conference_register', array( 'id' => $value->id ) );
     }
}
```

Comment: You have to move the `$wpdb->delete` statement above the result set query, since you're obtaining the results, displaying them, then deleting the row.

Comment: Ok, I'll try that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to skip outputting the row if you are deleting it.  Something like this:

```
<?php
 foreach($results as $value){
    $delRow = "delete_registration_{$value->id}";
    if(isset($_POST[$delRow])){
        $wpdb->delete( 'conference_register', array( 'id' => $value->id ) );
    } else {
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td class='posts column-posts'>".$value->id."</td>";
        echo "<td class='email column-email'>".$value->email."</td>";
        echo "<td class='description column-description'><div id='col-container'>".$value->details."</div></td>";
        echo "<td class='posts column-posts'><input type='submit' name= $delRow value='delete'/></td>";
        echo "</tr>";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can avoid displaying the row if you are deleting the row.

```
foreach($results as $value){
    if(isset($_POST[$delRow])){
        $wpdb->delete( 'conference_register', array( 'id' => $value->id ) );
    } 
    else {
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td class='posts column-posts'>".$value->id."</td>";
        echo "<td class='email column-email'>".$value->email."</td>";
        echo "<td class='description column-description'><div id='col-container'>".$value->details."</div></td>";
        $delRow = "delete_registration_{$value->id}";
        echo "<td class='posts column-posts'><input type='submit' name= $delRow value='delete'/></td>";
        echo "</tr>";
     }
}
```